# Win32 client size and an incorrect size

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So for a game project I am creating a game window (of course), but I only know the client size of the window and not the actual size. I know how to calculate the size but I am getting incorrect results when I am testing to see the size of the client area (should be the same as the input).

```
void NewWindow(width, height)
{
    // Code setting things up here.
        if (!fullscreen) // Convert client size to window size.
        {
            style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

            RECT r = RECT();
            r.top = 0;
            r.bottom = height;
            r.left = 0;
            r.right = width;

            AdjustWindowRect(&r, WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX |     WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, FALSE);

            w = r.right;
            h = r.bottom;
        }

        hWnd = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, title, style, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, w, h, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), (LPVOID)NULL);
}
```

And the code for getting the client size is:

```
Size Game::GetClientSize()
{
    RECT r = RECT();
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);

    return Size(r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top);
}
```

I am not sure where the problem is, because AdjustWindowRect seems to be outputting a value larger than what I put in...

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: In addition to the answers already given, be aware that `AdjustWindowRect` as of old had a number of bugs, e.g. incorrect results for window with menu line. And bugs in Windows have a tendency to persist. They become part of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The style you pass to `AdjustWindowRect` should be the same style you pass to `CreateWindow`.  Otherwise they will mismatch.  You also need to calculate width as right - left, and height as bottom - top, since the adjusted rect usually has a negative origin relative to the origin of the client area.

Answer (score 6):

Sure it is; `AdjustWindowRect()` inflates the rectangle to add room for the border and title bar you specified; in your case the left and top values are (probably) becoming negative, thus right and bottom do not represent the width and height. Calculate the width and height with r.right - r.left and r.bottom - r.top, as you do in your 2nd example function.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665(v=vs.85).aspx "A window rectangle is the smallest rectangle that completely encloses the window, which includes the client area and the nonclient area."

Answer (score 0):

```
HWND windowHandle = NULL;
WNDCLASS wndClass;
wndclassex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndclassex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndclassex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndclassex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndclassex.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclassex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndclassex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndclassex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wndclassex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndclassex.lpszClassName = L"Wnd";
RegisterClass(&wndClass);
RECT rt = {0, 0, 640, 480};
AdjustWindowRect(&rt, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
windowHandle = CreateWindow(L"Wnd", L"Wnd", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 10, 10, rt.right - rt.left, rt.bottom - rt.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL); 
ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
```